# Ng-Repeat nested in ng-virtual-repeat isn't working

Tags: html, angularjs, virtual, repeat

I'm working on a project for work where we display a dynamic table to a user. This table shows them a list of companies they are associated with, and the columns of that table can be specified by the user, where the columns correspond to properties of the company objects being displayed. Here is a snipped of my code:

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" style="height: 500px;">
    <div md-virtual-repeat="company in companies" flex>
        <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">{{::company[filter]}}</div>
    </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Where filters is a list of columns the user wants to see. However, Angular is simply displaying nothing. I know that the data is there and I can display the data just fine if I don't use the virtual repeat, however there can potentially be 10k+ companies in the list, and eventually they will need to be data-bound, so the virtual repeat is almost necessary.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to implement a table in the manner I'm describing?

Also under consideration would be refactoring using React instead, would React be better equipped to build this kind of table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was the interaction between the repeat-container and the div that had the repeat directive on it. Replacing the div with an md-list-item resolved the issue.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" style="height: 500px;">
    <md-list-item md-virtual-repeat="company in companies" flex>
        <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">{{::company[filter]}}</div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```